# How can I optimize my controller so it runs 1 query instead of 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Below is the controller of an application I am making in Laravel 9. It runs the same SQL 3 times to get the `id`. Is there a way to optimize it, so it just runs once?

```php
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('products.index', [
            'products' => product::paginate(6)->withQueryString()
        ]);
    }

    public function show($id, $name = null)
    {
        // Checks if product exists
        if (!product::find($id)) {
            return dd('Product not found');
        }

        $slug = Str::of(product::find($id)->name)->slug('-');

        //Checks if product name is set
        if (!$name || $name != $slug) {
            return redirect()->route('products.show', [
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $slug
            ]);
        }

        //if all above is coorect then return view
        return view('products.show', [
            'product' => product::find($id)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: save what is returned from `Product::find(...)` to a variable then you don't need to keep calling that method

Comment: Or look into https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use variable `$product`.

```
class ProductController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return view('products.index', [
            'products' => product::paginate(6)->withQueryString()
        ]);
    }

    public function show($id, $name = null) {

        $product = product::find($id);

        //Checks if product exists
        if (!$product) {
            return dd('Product not found');
        }

        $slug = Str::of($product->name)->slug('-');

        //Checks if product name is set
        if (!$name || $name != $slug) {
            return redirect()->route('products.show', [
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $slug
            ]);
        }

        //if all above is coorect then return view
        return view('products.show', [
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oke... Im stupid i had in mind that i would save the sql query as the variable but ofcorse laravel makes it in to a collection. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

#### variable variable variable!

> A variable in PHP is a name of memory location that holds data. In PHP, a variable is declared using $ sign followed by variable name.
> The main way to store information in the middle of a PHP program is by
> using a variable.

so a variable can stand for a value in all over of your code block!
try to define a variable for your query, then try to call it wherever your code need to use it:

```
$product = product::find($id);
```

Answer (score -2):

In your `public function show($id, $name = null)` fetch the value of id into a variable first:
`$productById = product::find($id);`

Subsequently in the function use `$productById` everywhere instead of `product::find($id)`.

(I just described what @lagbox commented in a more elaborated way.)

Comment: Instead of `$productById`, just use `$product`

Comment: I "fixed" my answer in using the class `product` for the call, but to prevent confusion between `$product` and `product` I still would prefer `$productById`

Comment: I know it is a "preference" for you, but follow PSR... It should be `$product` because you are getting a `Product` or `null`, it does not matter if it is from a service, from and ID, or whatever... Follow standards...

Comment: I'm not so deep into PHP but willing to learn, could you point me to the right PSR please, @matiaslauriti, so I can get rid of other bad habits as well? I looked at https://www.php-fig.org/psr/ but didn't find any recommendations for local variable namings, but as no database related stuff is there, I probably searched in the wrong place.

Comment: I was not able to find a `PSR` stating this, but I am talking based on experience, I read a lot of source code from Laravel and other good devs that constantly release packages and "we" all follow the same standard. [This](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/ab9e2045e0d8649cd84de411d0332bdd5fe763a3/src/Bridge/UserRepository.php#L54) is one example, [this](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/14b0a3cabb195540dc5c35cb98cb1d0fbdd0d848/src/Console/ClearCommand.php#L49) is another from Laravel Horizon (even with `arrays`, not only `objects`)